# How to retrieve an element with specific attribute using LINQ to XML with multiple elements with same name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, linq-to-xml

If I was retrieving a single element, I can use to pull an element named `Name`.

```
<li><span>System Name:</span>@(Model.Configuration.Root.Element("Name").Value)</li>
```

But, when I have multiple elements with the same name, it tells me `Sequence contains no elements` even though if I do it from code-behind, it gives me elements.

XML file:

```
<root>
    <Port Num="1">
        <Device>
            <Firmware>1.0</Firmware> 
        </Device>
    </Port>
    <Port Num="2">
        <Device>
            <Firmware>1.0</Firmware> 
        </Device>
    </Port>
</root>
```

CSHTML file:

```
<li><span>Port: 1</span>Firmware: @(
Model.Configuration.Root.Elements("Port")
.Where(a=>a.Attribute("Num").Equals("1")).First()
.Element("Device").Element("Firmware").Value)</li>
```

I want to retrieve the Firmware number (1.0) from Port #1.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Razor.

Comment: @Serge: That's not what he's comparing.

Comment: My bad, misread it ^^

Answer (score 3):

`.Attribute()` return an `XAttribute` object, which can never be equal to a string.

You want to compare the attribute's value:

```
Model.Configuration.Root.Elements("Port")
    .First(e => e.Attribute("Num").Value == "1")
    .Element("Device").Element("Firmware").Value
```